# yum install fails with HTTP 403 trying to access repomd.xml

Tags: http, proxy, fedora, yum, http-proxy

I'm trying to install a package on a old Fedora 20 virtual machine.

**`yum install`**`<the_package_name>` results in a failure with an **HTTP 403** error:

```
http://download.fedoraproject.org/<...(truncated)...>/repomd.xml:
[Errno 14] HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden
```

My web-browser can't see anything at `http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/updates/20` so I realize FC20 is no more supported (EOL) and its repository URL has changed. So I fix the baseurl in `/etc/yum.repos.d/fedora.repo` to look like this:

```
baseurl=http://archives.fedoraproject.org/<...(truncated)...>
```

I'm sure the URL is now correct, because I can download `repomd.xml` using `curl` or `wget`, and access it in my web browser...

But `yum install <the_package_name>` continues to fail with an **HTTP 403** error! It can't access `repomd.xml` at the correct URL:

```
http://archives.fedoraproject.org/<...(truncated)...>/repomd.xml:
[Errno 14] HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden
```

Can you help me overcome this issue and install packages on this old Fedora (FC 20)?

---

Note 1: I'm working from behind a proxy (not my choice).

Note 2: Upgrading my Fedora 20 to Fedora 21 or 22 is not an option either.

Comment: Do you have the proxy credentials specified for yum? That error is probably coming from the proxy if you don't.

Comment: Is it in any of the other repo files? Does `yum clean metadata && yum install git` work better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the suggestions (from Etan Reisner) that helped me solve the issue:

- Check the proxy configuration in `/etc/yum.conf`
- Check all YUM .repo files are using the up-to-date Fedora repo URL
- Launch `yum clean metadata` to ensure YUM uses the updated .repo files contents
- Try again `yum install <the_package>`

Answer (score 7):

`subscription-manager refresh` did the trick on a RHEL 7.9 server box.

Answer (score -1):

Created VPC Endpoint and allowed access to packages, repos and amazonlinux resources.

```
{"Version": "03-19-2021",
"Statement": [
{"Sid": "Amazon Linux AMI Repository Access",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Principal": "*",
"Action": "s3:GetObject",
"Resource": [ "arn:aws:s3:::packages.*.amazonaws.com/*", "arn:aws:s3:::repo.*.amazonaws.com/*", "arn:aws:s3:::amazonlinux.*.amazonaws.com/*" ]
}]}
```

Refer to https://blog.saieva.com/category/aws/