# Error while installing namp in redhat

Tags: linux, unix

```
[root@Redhat7 ~]# yum install nmap
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/server/7/x86_64/debug/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 403 - Forbidden
Trying other mirror.
```

Comment: Try googling for something like `yum install mirror change` adding to it your  system type?

Comment: Yes i did try and apply possible solution but didn't work. fyi, i used this source https://access.redhat.com/solutions/313563

Answer (score 0):

Not my answer but check this:

- Check the proxy configuration in /etc/yum.conf
- Check all YUM .repo files are using the up-to-date Fedora repo URL
- Launch yum clean metadata to ensure YUM uses the updated .repo files contents
- Try again yum install

Something similar was [solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32483036/yum-install-fails-with-http-403-trying-to-access-repomd-xml).